# UserControl with Dependancy Properties to replace repetative set of similiar controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls, datatemplate

Sorry for the terrible Question Title, I don't know how to phrase this, feel free to comment.

I am working on a WPF desktop app using the MVVM pattern. I have a great number of text fields on my ViewModel, all of which I want to display using the pattern below (greatly simplified):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomePredicate}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>

    <Label Content="SomeHeader:"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />

</StackPanel>
```

The display always consists of:

- A Predicate for determining if the StackPanel should be shown
- A string used as header text. This can be set in XAML, it doesn't have to come from the viewmodel
- A binding to the Textblock text string on the ViewModel

I would really love to be able to define these like this:

```
<MyHeaderedTextBlockControl Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}"
                            Header="SomeHeader:"
                            Predicate="{Binding SomePredicate}"/>
```

Can this be done? I tried doing it with a UserControl but had no idea what I was doing.

It is important to me that the binding modes remain working, ie if the `Text` binding is in `OneWay` or `TwoWay` mode, the `TextBlock` should update when the `Text` property on the ViewModel raises `OnPropertyChanged`.

I also dont like the idea of doing this with a View and a ViewModel for each such text property, because then I have to create those ViewModels and wire them up for updates etc. I want a solution that I can implement in the View, ideally the ViewModel shouldn't even know about it.

Comment: I din't get this line : "I want a solution that I can implement in the View, ideally the ViewModel shouldn't even know about it." You would need to create Text, Header, Predicate property anyways in viewmodel.

Comment: @anivas Yes, ofcourse, but those properties are already there. The ViewModel exposes a boolean property for the predicate and a String property for the Text. The Header I will define in the View's XAML each time I build such a construct.

Comment: You can create an usercontrol with those properties as dependency properites of the control, if you have many of those textboxes (I hope you have a collection of text, header and boolean) you can create an itemscontrol with datatemplate. Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UserControls you define dependency properties in your code and forward them to the "template" via binding, e.g.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.HeaderedTextBlock"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="control">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Predicate, ElementName=control}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <Label Content="{Binding Header, ElementName=control}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=control}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
namespace Test.UserControls
{
    public partial class HeaderedTextBlock : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderedTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PredicateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Predicate", typeof(bool), typeof(HeaderedTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
        public bool Predicate
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(PredicateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PredicateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderedTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public HeaderedTextBlock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Would something like this work for you?

Comment: That is absolutely perfect and pretty awesome! Thanks a lot!